# PostgreSQL Invalid Token at position 1 of line 3

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

I've written this simple query using PostgreSQL 9.4:

```
UPDATE t.pro 
SET 
utente_ultima_modifica = 'io',
data_fine_val = now(), 
data_ultima_modifica = now()
WHERE cf = 'cf'
```

When I try to execute it, a popup Information window that says

```
Invalid Token 'utente_ultima_modifica' at position 1 of line 3
```

appears. When I click 'ok' in the result tab, I see the successfull message

> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,20 sec)

but when I check the data into the table  t.pro nothing has changed.

Hope someone will be able to help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a column named `utente_ultima_modifica` in your `pro` table located inside `t` schema? 0 rows affected means that the UPDATE run successfully but found no rows to update matching criteria. How many rows do you get when executing `select * from t.pro where cf = 'cf'` ?

Comment: I've solved it. I was passing a wrong value in the where statement.

Comment: __Voted to close__: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers